# Nested category parent id

Tags: php, arguments, rule

i have mysql table (exe_categories)

| id, title, parent_id, extension |

```
 `<ul>
     <li>Parentcat</li>
        <ul>
           <li>ParentSub</li>
           <li>ParentSub</li>
           <li>ParentSub</li>
       </ul>
     <li>Parentcat</li>
       <ul>
          <li>ParentSub</li>
          <li>ParentSub</li>
          <li>ParentSub</li>
       </ul>       
 </ul>`
```

and i want to show a nested category list and subcategory using 2 arguments

first-argument is (parent_id) (0)

AND second argument is (extension)  'com_extension'

I want to show up the nested categories titles and path for the 2 arguments above

i have used this code below and works fine but i cant have another argument for extension argument.

```
<?php

  function query($parent_id) { //function to run a query
$query = mysql_query ( "SELECT * FROM exe_categories WHERE parent_id=$parent_id");
return $query;
  }
function has_child($query) { //This function checks if the menus has childs or not
$rows = mysql_num_rows ( $query );
 if ($rows > 0) {
     return true;
 } else {
     return false;
}
  }
function fetch_menu($query) {
 while ( $result = mysql_fetch_array ( $query ) ) {
     $id = $result ['id'];
            $extension = $result['com_bids'];
     $title = $result ['title'];
    $menu_link = $result ['menu_link'];
    echo "<li><a href='{$menu_link}'><span>{$title}</span></a>"; 

     if (has_child ( query ( $id ) )) {
                    echo "<div>";
                    echo '<ul role="menu" class="fofc">';

                    fetch_menu ( query ( $id) );   
                    echo "</ul>";
                    echo "</div>";
    }

              echo "</li>";  
}
   }
 fetch_menu (query(1)); //call this function with 1 parent id

?>
```

the code above will fetch list of categories starting from parent_id=0 which works great only that i cant have another rule for my extension column .
any help will be appreciated :)

The Html output is  like this

- Parentcat

  - ParentSub
  - ParentSub
  - ParentSub
- Parentcat

  - ParentSub
  - ParentSub
  - ParentSub

Comment: Could you give us an example of what this nested structure will look like?  On output and some example data from your table.

Comment: <ul><li><ul><li></li></ul></li></ul>

Comment: ok i just edit the html list .

Comment: What do you mean by another rule for your `extension` column?  Are you trying to restrict results?  Or are you asking how you can output multiple parent/child results?